# Make a div resizable in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, draggable, resizable

I'm trying to get a div (with an image inside) to be draggable and resizable in Angular2/4.
So far i succeded to make it draggable with "angular2-draggable" but I can't find a module/directive that allow me to resize my div.

I tried a bunch of module i found on the net but can't get it to work.

Does anyone know a module that he successfully used that is well explained ?
If not, can I use jquery-ui with angular to get the job done ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: I used fabric.js

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `angular2-resizable`?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-resizable

Comment: Yes and it didn't work but another module did (the same developer) https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-resizable-element

Comment: Actually, angular2-resizable is deprecated, and now, as @NafaaAzaiez says, it's https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-resizable-element/blob/master/demo/demo.component.ts the supported and updated child ;)

Comment: Just go through github.com/mattlewis92/angular-resizable-element issue id 77. You will get how they make fool to developer in name of support.

Answer (score 1):

I found a library that does everything I want to do (drag, resize, rotate, fill with img, and much much more) **fabric.js**